# php self() with current object's constructor

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, static, self

What's the proper way to get `new self()` to use the current instance's constructor? In other words, when I do:

```
class Foo{
  function create(){
    return new self();
  }
}

Class Bar extends Foo{
}

$b = new Bar();
echo get_class($b->create());
```

I want to see: `Bar` instead of: `Foo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static function create()
{
    $class = get_called_class();

    return new $class();
}
```

This should work.

```
class Foo{
  public static function create()
    {
        $class = get_called_class();

        return new $class();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{
}

$a = Foo::create();
$b = Bar::create();

echo get_class($a), PHP_EOL, get_class($b);
```

Shows:

```
Foo Bar
```

**UPD:**

If you want non-statics, then:

```
<?php
class Foo{
  public function create()
    {
        $class = get_class($this);

        return new $class();
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo{}

$a = new Bar();
$b = $a->create();

echo get_class($a), PHP_EOL, get_class($b);
?>
```

Shows:

```
Bar Bar
```

Comment: This only works with static classes though - whereas the OP's demo code shows creating instances of the class and not calling static methods.

Comment: Thanks. I'll correct. But strange, that he just ommitig `new` keyword. I don't see why he needs this.

Comment: Actually get_called_class seems to work for me with static and non-static functions. So I guess I'll choose this answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Foo{
  function create(){
    $c = get_class($this);
    return new $c();
  }
}

Class Bar extends Foo{
}

$b = new Bar();
echo get_class($b->create());
```

Store the class type in a temp variable and then return a new instance of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Bar extends Foo {
function create(){
return self;
}}
```

If you call a function from a child class then it if it will search the nearest parent to call it. This is inheritance.

The idea is to use polymorphism in this situation. Redeclaring a function from child override it's parent's activity. If you want to run it's parent function too then you have to call it like `parent::callee();`

Comment: The whole point is to not have to overload the function on each class that inherits the main.