# Static 'constructor' in abstract static context

Tags: php, static, abstract, extends

I'm having a problem. Basically what I want to di is use a static constructor to return a instaniated object with the parameters passed to this static function (which acts like a constructor).

So what I want to do is:

```
$urls = Urls::st__construct("wp_","fk_arv_");
$main = ClassName::st__construct("wp_","fk_arv_");
```

with:

```
    abstract class Entity
{
...
    public static function st__construct($table_prefix,$key_prefix){
        return new self($table_prefix,$key_prefix);
    }

       function __construct($table_prefix,$key_prefix) {
        $this->table_prefix     = $table_prefix;
        $this->key_prefix       = $key_prefix;
       }
}
```

Classes Url and ClassName both extend Entity. I expected 'self' to return Url or ClassName, since I call the static method via the extended class (which should inherit the static method from it's parent). However, it's trying to return a new Entity (which ofcourse fails). How can I do this properly?

Comment: which version of PHP?

Comment: `new static` instead of `new self`?

Comment: This: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963547/php-self-with-current-objects-constructor/

Comment: version < 5.3.0, so I can't use get_called_class